# Run-time error '438': Object does't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

Following macro nearly works flawless up to one specific line.

```
Sub Top15()

Dim Top15 As Worksheet

Dim lastROW As Long
Dim last15ROW As Long

Dim rangeC As Range
Dim rangeH As Range
Dim rangeI As Range
Dim rangeJ As Range
Dim rangeK As Range
Dim rangeL As Range
Dim rangeM As Range
Dim rangeN As Range
Dim pasteRange As Range

Set Top15 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("03")

lastROW = Top15.Range("C" & Top15.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
last15ROW = Top15.Range("C" & Top15.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 16

Set rangeC = Top15.Range("C" & lastROW & ":C" & last15ROW)
Set rangeH = Top15.Range("H" & lastROW & ":H" & last15ROW)
Set rangeI = Top15.Range("I" & lastROW & ":I" & last15ROW)
Set rangeJ = Top15.Range("J" & lastROW & ":J" & last15ROW)
Set rangeK = Top15.Range("K" & lastROW & ":K" & last15ROW)
Set rangeL = Top15.Range("L" & lastROW & ":L" & last15ROW)
Set rangeM = Top15.Range("M" & lastROW & ":M" & last15ROW)
Set rangeN = Top15.Range("N" & lastROW & ":N" & last15ROW)

With Top15
    rangeC.Formula = "=TEXT(WEEKNUM(TODAY()),""0#"")" 'CW
    rangeH.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())),"""",INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT(INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),""0#""))" 'REF
    rangeI.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT(INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1,""0#""),H:H,1,FALSE),2)+1=INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),1),1)" 'open weeks
    rangeJ.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,3,FALSE),"""")" 'Issue description
    rangeK.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,4,FALSE),"""")" 'action
    rangeL.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,5,FALSE),"""")" 'reason
    rangeM.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,6,FALSE),"""")" 'missing component
    rangeN.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,7,FALSE),"""")" 'expected D CW

Set pasteRange = .Range(rangeC.Address & ":" & rangeN.Address)

pasteRange.Copy
pasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With

End Sub
```

The first three functions work but I'm getting the run-time error at the third one:

```
With Top15
    rangeC.Formula = "=TEXT(WEEKNUM(TODAY()),""0#"")" 'CW
    rangeH.Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())),"""",INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT(INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),""0#""))" 'REF
    rangeI.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT(INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1,""0#""),H:H,1,FALSE),2)+1=INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),INDIRECT(""C""&ROW()),1),1)" 'open weeks
    rangeJ.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,3,FALSE),"""")" 'Issue description
    rangeK.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,4,FALSE),"""")" 'action
    rangeL.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,5,FALSE),"""")" 'reason
    rangeM.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,6,FALSE),"""")" 'missing component
    rangeN.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,7,FALSE),"""")" 'expected D CW
```

This is the formula that is giving me the run-time error->

```
rangeJ.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,3,FALSE),"""")" 'Issue description
```

Anyone knows why VBA has a problem with that formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have mispelled the range.Formula

Your line:
rangeJ.Forumla =

Should be:
rangeJ.Formula =

Happens twice:

```
rangeJ.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,3,FALSE),"""")" 'Issue description
rangeK.Forumla = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP((INDIRECT(""D""&ROW())&""/""&TEXT((INDIRECT(""C""&ROW())-1),""0#"")),$H:$N,4,FALSE),"""")" 'action
```

Please mark answer as correct if you agree.

Hope it helps!

Comment: And this is why you **always** should **`Option Explicit`** at the top of your code.